# After 10.11.1 upgrade USB hub on Dell monitor won't mount drives

Tags: external-disk, macos

I use a Dell 2715Q 4k screen with a USB3 hub.

With 10.11.0, I was able to mount my USB drives for time machine.

After the update to 10.11.1, the Macbook does not see the USB drives.

I can connect the drives directly to the Mac.

However, this worked 100% before the 10.11.1 upgrade.

MacBook Pro with Retina display,  OS X Yosemite (10.10.4), 2015

Comment: My Dell screens [different models, 2713, but might be relevant] are often loathe to  connect devices from a cold boot, but will after a restart. Have you checked after restarting? Also have you checked the USB Hubs can be seen in About this Mac/System Report/USB ?

Comment: I was able to get the drives to recognize if I switch from the left USB to the right USB. I have not yet restarted, although I did the Dell major restart of unplug everything, hold monitor button 10 seconds etc.